Cannot find OAuth consent screen or project in Google Cloud Console for an old Login with Google setup
I set up Google login for my app about six years ago using the Google Developer Console. Now, I want to add a domain to the allowed origins list. However, when I log in to the Google Cloud Console, I cannot find the project or the OAuth consent screen setup that I originally used.
It seems like the Google Developer Console has evolved since I last worked on this, and I’m unsure how to locate the old project or make the necessary changes. Has anyone experienced this issue or can guide me on how to proceed?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If you remember using any specific APIs, go to the API Library and search for them. The associated projects should appear in the list.

I'm using https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth I don't see one in API Library
